# Java equivalent of PHP's call_user_func()

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is calling methods/objects with string variables.

I've got '`foo`' and '`bar`' and need to do `foo.bar()`

Is there something like PHP's `call_user_func()`? Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could you reflection as others suggest, however it's a complicated and slow thing. Hwoever Java isn't designed to work like this. If you'd explain what you are trying to achieve in the big picture, there may be better ways, such as a Map of Strings to interface implementations, that would be a better use of the abilities of Java. Or maybe you are using Java for the wrong job.

Comment: I've got a jsp file(gui.jsp) and it takes two params like gui.jsp?class=Users&method=getUsers so gui.jsp calls Users.getUsers() and exports result as xml or json regarding to user's choice. My point is classes should be called dynamically. I'm so new with Java. So you are welcome to suggest any other kind of structures.

Comment: You realize you are creating a huge security hole? What if somebody called `gui.jsp?class=System&method=getProperties` or `gui.jps?class=System&method=exit`?

Comment: To be frank that sounds dangerous. What you are attempting would expose the internal workings of your classes to the web, and one small bug may lead to you allowing people executing any method in your classes leading to potential big security holes.

The first though I'd have would be to use a Web-Framework (e.g. Struts, Wicket, I don't know if there are better/simpler choices, since I don't do much web development with Java) which allow you to map URLs and URL parameters to methods of Controller objects.

Comment: Thanks for your concerns but only a group of developers **who won't abuse the structure** use it for temporarily on local network and I also know what I'm doing. I'm putting gui.jsp in front of other classes to allow others to see results in one view. It has to be like this for a while. Actual url structure will be `/users/getUsers.jsp`. It (I mean gui.jsp) is kind of testing page for us which means no need to worry for this kind of security rules but thanks again for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you should use reflection.

official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

your case could look like this:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("foo");
Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("bar", new Class [0] );
method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, new Object[0]);
```

where `objectToInvokeOn` is the instance/object (of class foo) you want to call on. In case you have it.

Otherwise you should go for:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("foo");
Object objectToInvokeOn = c.newInstance();
Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("bar", new Class [0] );
method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, new Object[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called reflection in Java: Refer [**this tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) for details.

```
     foo fooObject = new foo(); //not using reflection, but you can if you need to

     //use reflection on your class()not object to get the method
     Method method = foo.class.getMethod("bar", null);

     //Invoke the method on your object(not class)
     Object bar = method.invoke(fooObject, null);
```

As a side note: You class names shoul start with `UpperCase` e.g. `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no totally equivalent function in theory, because Java is pure OOP, and thus it doesn't provide a global scope function caller - which by the way is a crappy intent of replicating reflection itself, being PHP functions not proper objects at the time.

As already stated, you can use [Java's reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), which behaves like [PHP's](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

**TL;DR**

You can emulate `call_user_func*` stuff with Java reflection classes [Class, Method, Field].

Answer (score 0):

If you have Interfaces that the class implements, then you can create a **proxy** class with a generic method handling. But that is even more specific than reflection.